# Given a metric, calculate the volume of a subset of the space.

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, general-relativity

The metric of the $3$-sphere is given by the line element $$ds^2=\frac{a^2}{1-r^2}dr^2+a^2r^2d\theta^2 + a^2r^2\sin^2\theta d\phi^2$$ Find the volume of the region $r\leq r_0$.

I am calculating the volume of the integral using the formula $$\int_0^{r_0}\int_0^\pi \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{a^3r^2\sin\theta}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}d\phi d\theta dr$$

Is this integral correct? I'm somehow not getting the correct answer. Are the limits correct?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.lsw.uni-heidelberg.de/users/mcamenzi/Ex3_Sol_2010.pdf and you are looking at the volume only right? You don't need the integral for this.

Comment: @Nameless: I don't understand your reference. Yes, the integral is set up correctly, we have to presume (Do they tell you the $\theta$ and $\phi$ limits? This is a metric on the (open) $3$-ball in spherical coordinates, yes.) In what sense is this supposed to be the $3$-sphere you're working with, fierydemon? Do you mean $3$-ball?